# Java shift right outputting negative value

Tags: java

i'm really confused with, well it's best if I show my code first so here's what I got.

```
void dumpInt(int x) throws IOException {
    if ( true ) {
        //8388638
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        writer.writeByte(x&0xff);
        writer.writeByte((x>>8)&0xff);
        writer.writeByte((x >> 16) & 0xfff);
        writer.writeByte((x>>24)&0xff);
        outputStream.write(x & 0xff);
        outputStream.write((x >> 8) & 0xff);
        outputStream.write((x >> 16) & 0xff);
        outputStream.write((x >> 24) & 0xff);
        System.out.println((x >> 16) & 0xff);
        if(x == 8388638){
            String xz = "";
            byte[]array = outputStream.toByteArray();
            System.out.println(array[2]+" | " + (char)array[2]);
        }
    } else {
        writer.writeInt(x);
    }
}
```

this works fine but when I do dumpInt(8388638), I get some weird occurrences.
`writer.writeByte((x >> 16) & 0xfff)` writes -128 to the writer
Im clueless as why that is.

The same thing happens for `outputStream.write((x >> 16) & 0xff);` but when I run `System.out.println((x >> 16) & 0xff);` it outputs 128(positive)

Does anybody know why this is and how I can correct it?
(Sorry i'm somewhat *experienced* in java but im not the best by any means so if this is a really simple fix my bad)

Comment: -128 is the right answer.  128 is _not a byte in Java._

Comment: Do you realise that a byte in Java ranges from -128 to 127?

Comment: What is `writer`?

Comment: @Sweeper  really?
I tested this  [link](https://i.imgur.com/SbZvUx3.png) and it gave me an output of [link](https://i.imgur.com/JYRCrov.png)
(Sorry for the link, it formatted really weird when I used a codeblock)

Comment: @Sweeper `writer` is a DataOutputStream

Comment: Sorry, did not see your first comment. You are not casting the whole result in that code. `(byte)(x>>16)&0xff` only casts `(x>>16)` to `byte`, and then you immediately converted back to `int` via `& 0xff`, because the `&` operator does numeric promotion.

Comment: `writer.writeByte((x >> 16) & 0xfff);` -- Why `0xfff` and not `0xff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytes in Java are *signed*, and have the range -128~127. You seem to be more familiar with the other decimal representation of a byte - the unsigned byte, having a range from 0 to 255. However, that doesn't exist in Java as a separate data type.

The following shows corresponding values between the two representations:

```
  signed    -128 -127 -126 ... -1   0   1   ...   126 127 128
unsigned    128  129  130  ... 255  0   1   ...   126 127 128
```

Note: these are not really different representations in binary. They have the same binary representation. It depends on whether you interpret the MSB as the sign bit or not.

You can convert from the signed version to the unsigned version by `Byte.toUnsignedInt`, and you can convert from the unsigned version to the signed version by casting to `byte`.

For some reason that you'd have to ask the API designers, `OutputStream.write` accepts unsigned bytes (as well as signed ones). How does Java do this if `byte` only ranges from -128 to 127? It accepts an `int` rather than a `byte`! This is the reason why your code compiles at all.

`write` (which `writeByte` also calls) converts the `int` 128 to a (signed) `byte` -128 and writes it into the stream. When you get the written bytes later, you are getting the converted signed `byte`. But in fact, in terms of the bits, 128 and -128 are the same `1000 0000`. It's just that Java insists on interpreting the first `1` as a sign bit.

As I said before, you *can* convert the `-128` to 128` if you prefer the other representation:

```
Byte.toUnsignedInt(-128) // 128
```

Note that the result must be an `int`, because the result is outside of `byte`'s range.

Answer (score 1):

In java, a byte has the range of `[-128, +127]`, as in, +128 is literally impossible. In fact, `-128` is how a byte that holds +128 is printed (in the sense that +128 is, in bits, `1000 0000`, and as a java byte, as they are signed, that is rendered as -128, because that's also `1000 0000`.

In other words, your app is working fine.

Your linked picture in your comment is due to you misunderstanding how parentheses and operator priority works in java.

> `System.out.println((byte)(x>>16)&0xff);`

resolves like so:

`(byte)(x>>16)` `&` `0xFF`

and as `0xFF` is an int (all numeric literals are always an int, unless they end in a capital `L`, then they are a long. You can't put a byte or short literal in java code), that's an operation between a byte and an int, and like all ops between bytes and ints, this is resolved by first upgrading the byte to an int, and then returning the result by doing the op on the two resulting ints. In other words, it is this:

`(int)((byte)(x>>16)` `&` `0xFF`

And that'd be +128.

Try this:

`(byte)((x>>16) & 0xFF)`. You'll find it prints `-128` as expected.

Comment: Oh I get it lmao
Thanks a lot now I can fix this somehow

Comment: @Anonymouss121 I have no idea how `writer` works, whatever that might be, but the usual java code will do the `0xFF` by itself, so all those `&0xFF` you got there is probably useless. But if they aren't, then your problem is that you have `&0xFFF` (3 Fs) in one of them (the x>>16 one, specifically). At least, that's in your paste.

Answer (score 1):

> The same thing happens for outputStream.write((x >> 16) & 0xff); but when I run System.out.println((x >> 16) & 0xff); it outputs 128(positive) Does anybody know why this is and how I can correct it?

```
int x = 8388638;
```

When you do the following:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream.write((x >> 16) & 0xff); 
System.out.println(outputStream.toByteArray()[0]);
```

You are printing a -128 because the value is `0b1000_0000` which is -128 in
two's complement form for a byte (the high order bit being the sign bit).

When you do this:

```
System.out.println((x >> 16) & 0xff);
```

`(x>>16)` is still an `int` and then the `&` masks off the top 24 bits. So the low order 8 bits print as an `int` and two's complement does not come into play.

For more information check out [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)